# Display and search through a JSON's items in Vue.js

Tags: css, ecmascript-6, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, axios

I have put together this small application which displays data from a JSON file known as "Users" in an HTML5 table.

I use Bootstrap 3, Axios and Vue.js 2 for this purpose.

Here is the code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        users: [],
        loading: true,
        errored: false,
        url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=500&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture",
        search: '',
        page: 1,
        perPage: 25,
        pages: [],
    },
    methods: {
        getUsers() {
            axios
                .get(this.url)
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data.results
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        },
        setPages(users) {
            this.pages.length = 0;
            var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(users.length / this.perPage);
            for (var index = 1; index <= numberOfPages; index++) {
                this.pages.push(index);
            }
        },
        paginate(users) {
            var page = this.page;
            var perPage = this.perPage;
            var from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
            var to = (page * perPage);
            return users.slice(from, to);
        },
        scrollToTop() {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 500);
            return false;
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getUsers();
    },
    watch: {
        displayedUsers() {
            this.setPages(this.searchResults);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        displayedUsers() {
            return this.paginate(this.searchResults);
        },
        searchResults() {
            this.page = 1;
            return this.users.filter((user) => {
                const {
                    first,
                    last
                } = user.name;
                const {
                    email
                } = user;
                const {
                    city
                } = user.location;
                const lowerCaseSearch = this.search.toLowerCase()
                return `${first} ${last}`.toLowerCase().match(lowerCaseSearch) ||
                    email.toLowerCase().match(lowerCaseSearch) ||
                    city.toLowerCase().match(lowerCaseSearch);
            });
        }
    },
    filters: {
        lowercase(value) {
            return value.toLowerCase();
        },
        capitalize(value) {
            return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
        },
        titlecase(value) {
            return value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function(match) {
                return match.toUpperCase();
            })
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.table-container {
  margin: 10px;
}
.table-container .panel-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-container .panel-heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.table-container .panel-heading h2 {
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-container .panel-heading .searchbox {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.table-container .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.table-container table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}
.table-container table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.table-container table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-container table tr th:first-child, .table-container table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr th:last-child, .table-container table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.table-container table tr td {
  padding: 2px 8px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-container table tr td .picture {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.table-container table tr td img {
  max-height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
}

.pagination {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.pagination li a:focus, .pagination li a:hover {
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <h2 class="pull-left">Users</h2>
      <div class="searchbox">
        <input type="text" v-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-right">#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>City</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(user, index) in displayedUsers">
              <td class="text-right">{{perPage * (page - 1) + index + 1}}</td>
              <td>
                <span class="picture">
                  <img :src="user.picture.thumbnail" :alt="user.name.first + ' ' + user.name.last" class="img-circle">
                </span>
                <span>{{user.name.first | capitalize}} {{user.name.last | capitalize}}</span>
              </td>
              <td><a :href="'mailto:' + user.email | lowercase">{{user.email | lowercase}}</a></td>
              <td>{{user.location.city | titlecase}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="text-center" aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
      <li @click="scrollToTop">
        <a href="#" @click="page = 1;" aria-label="First">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li @click="scrollToTop">
        <a href="#" v-if="page != 1" @click="page--;" aria-label="Previous">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page-1, page+4)" :class="{'active': page === pageNumber}" @click="scrollToTop"><a href="#" @click="page = pageNumber;">{{pageNumber}}</a></li>
      <li @click="scrollToTop">
        <a href="#" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length" aria-label="Next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li @click="scrollToTop">
        <a href="#" @click="page = pages.length;" aria-label="Last">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It works, but I am certain there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall the code looks fine. There aren't any drastic changes I would advise - just mostly a few simplifications. As far as the design goes it looks good, though it may be wise to add a spinner icon or some other indication while the data is loading, lest the user think nothing is happening. And it doesn't appear that anything happens when `errored` is set to true. Perhaps the UI should notify the user that there was a problem fetching the data.

The URL doesn't really change so it doesn't need to be in the `data` object. I would move it out to a constant.

```
const API_URL = "https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=500&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture";
```

---

I understand what the following block in the filter function of `searchResults()` is doing:

> ```
>             const {
>                 first,
>                 last
>             } = user.name;
>             const {
>                 email
>             } = user;
>             const {
>                 city
>             } = user.location;
> ```

But is it really necessary to define all of those things instead of just using the properties, as in below? I could maybe see a point for the nested properties but not so much for `user.email`...

```
return `${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}`.toLowerCase().match(lowerCaseSearch) ||
    user.email.toLowerCase().match(lowerCaseSearch) ||
    user.location.city.toLowerCase().match(lowerCaseSearch);
```

---

The following CSS rulesets could be combined:

> ```
> .table-container .panel-heading {
>   font-weight: bold;
> }
> .table-container .panel-heading {
>   display: flex;
>   align-items: center;
> }
> ```

The font-weight specification could be moved into the lower declaration block, unless you wanted to pull the bold specification out of the heading ruleset (i.e. `.table-container .panel-heading h2`) and combine it with the lone bold rule.